# Substring of a file

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring

I have a file that is structure like this :

```
var file = "a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d";
```

Now I would extract all letters "c" and "d" of this file and put those letter in array, structure like this:

```
   var array = [
                   [a,b,1],
                   [a,b,2],
                   [a,b,3],
                   [a,b,4],
                   [a,b,5]
             ];
```

How can I do that? It is possible?

--------------EDIT----------------------

And if I have an array structured like this?

```
exArray = [
             ["a":"one", "b":"two", "c":"three", "d":"four"],
             ["a":"five", "b":"six", "c":"seven", "d":"eight"]
          ];
```

The new array must be:

```
var array = [
                       [two,three,1],
                       [six,seven,2]
                 ];
```

Comment: So, you want to remove `c` and `d`, and put the remainder in the array?

Comment: that's either a regex or a double split, nothing that hard, apparently.

Comment: where does the 1, 2, 3... come from? and where is the b and d?

Comment: @NinaScholz 1,2,3.. are the index

Comment: @GianniPasquetta it would be a bit more clear if you did say _extract all letter "c" and letter "d"_ instead of _"b" and "c"_ :p

Comment: @GianniPasquetta: Then I have a working answer for you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your desired output, this will do the trick:

```js
var file = "a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d";
var array = file.split(", ") // Break up the original string on `", "`
                .map(function(element, index){
                    var temp = element.split('|');
                    return [temp[0], temp[1], index + 1];
                });

console.log(array);
alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```

The [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) converts your `file` string to an array like this:

```
["a|b|c|d", "a|b|c|d", "a|b|c|d", "a|b|c|d", "a|b|c|d"];
```

Then, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is called on that array, passing each `"a|b|c|d"`, along with it's position in the array to the callback, which splits the string, and returns an array containing the first 2 elements, and it's `id` (index + 1).

---

You can also do the callback in the `map` slightly differently:

```
.map(function(element, index){
    return element.split('|').slice(0, 2).concat(index + 1);
});
```

This method uses the same split, then uses [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the first 2 elements from the array, and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)s the `id` to the array with 2 elements returned from `slice`.
This way, you don't use a temporary variable, there:

```
element                // "a|b|c|d"
    .split('|')        // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    .slice(0, 2)       // ["a", "b"]
    .concat(index + 1) // ["a", "b", id]
```

Comment: @GianniPasquetta: The string you want to format in your edit isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: And with this new edit? Please help me one more time

Comment: I'd suggest you post a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`split()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [`map()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var file = "a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d";

file.split(',').map(function(el, index) { 
   var arr = el.split('|'); 
   return [arr[0], arr[1], index+1]
});
```

Comment: This does not give a correct answer. "c" and "d" is still kept in the resultant array where it doesn't form the correct output format either.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, but the solution is almost the same as some other. There is not too much possibilities here :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
function transformFile(file) {
    return file.split(',').map(function(el) {
        return el.split('|'); }
    );
}
```

`split()` function transforms a string to an array taking its parameter as an item separator. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

`map()` function takes an array and iterates over every item changing it in the way you define in the callback function. And here's the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

So **we're taking a string and first we split it in four arrays** - each containing `a|b|c|d` string. Then **we take each of those string and split it again** (this time using `|` as separator) to transform `a|b|c|d` string into `[a, b, c, d]` array. So after those operations we end up with an array of arrays.

Comment: That's interesting, but it would be great to explain what the split does and the map does, the OP is probably confused, hence I would really upvote that answer with a clearer explanation :P

Answer (score -1):

Try to use split() and replace() function.

```
var file = "a|b|c|d,a|b|c|d,a|b|c|d,a|b|c|d, a|b|c|d";
var NewFile =[];
var i = 1;
file.split(',').forEach(function(el) { 

  NewFile.push( el.replace("c|d", i).split("|"));
  i++;

});
console.log(NewFile);
```

Comment: What if `c` and `d` are placeholders for variable strings?